# Embedded videos not showing up in iPad landscape view

Tags: ios, ipad, video, embed, landscape

I am building a website that has embedded videos, mostly from YouTube. The videos are not showing up in landscape view for iPad. Any idea why or how I can fix this? THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i will need more information about this in order to be able to provide you with a specific answer.

Can you see the video on portrait mode but not on landscape?

There is a fair chance you have your YouTube app hidden via a jailbreak tweak, or you have restrictions enabled. Restrictions can be enabled without a jailbreak.As it turns out, having the YouTube app hidden can result in embedded videos not to show. YouTube videos on the actual YouTube site will still play fine regardless, but embedded videos can give you problems if your stock YouTube app is hidden, or you have restrictions enabled.

If your iPad is not jailbroken, then go under Settings/General/Restrictions and ensure that the YouTube app is set to On.

PS: I would also advise you to update your iOS version to the latest one.

I hope this solves your problem, if not then please provide more information like:
1)if your iPad is jailbroken or not
2)the version of iOS you are running
3)a link to one of your pages (or the code) 
4)verify that this problem occurs in more than 1 device (to check that it is not a device issue)

Regards,
Thanos